# Google-finance syntax for date of all time low of a stock

Tags: date, google-sheets, indexing, min, google-finance

What's `GOGGLEFINANCE` Syntax do I use to get the DATE of ALL TIME LOW of the Stock?

I am using `- =MIN(GOOGLEFINANCE("ABBV","low","01/01/1980",TODAY(),7))`

It is giving me ALL TIME LOW Quote of `ABBV`. How do I get the corresponding date for all time low?

Answer (score 0):

It sorts all prices from lowest to highest and takes first date in the list:

```
=to_date(index(sort((GOOGLEFINANCE("ABBV","low","01/01/1980",TODAY(),7)),2,1),1,1))
```

Comment: Thanks! So I am using the same syntax as you have stated, but for the stocks listed on India's NSE. Let's take HDFC Bank stock. The All time low for this stock was 5.20 on 12 Feb 1999. So I am using the syntax as you have stated replacing ABBV with NSE:HDFCBANK. The ATL date it returns is 15 September 2015 :(( Please help!